# Week number of a year in dateformat

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to get the year I use the format `YYYY`, and month `MM`, and so on. I am looking to see if there is a format to get the week number of the year.

The date that I am using as example is `2008-03-09 16:05:07.000`, and I would like to know the week number which is `11` in this case. Is there a way to retrieve `11` programmatically?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no format that provides the weeknumber, but you can get it in this way easily:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cul = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
int weekNum = cul.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
    DateTime.Now, 
    System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, 
    DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

- [`CultureInfo.Calendar` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.calendar.aspx)
- [`Calendar.GetWeekOfYear` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

To answer your comment how to get the quarter of a year of a given `DateTime`:

```
int quarter = (int)((DateTime.Now.Month - 1) / 3) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I tried the same thing which was available in one of the posts. Now I tried a similar thing for GetDayofWeek like this.                                      System.Int32 dayofweek = ((Int32)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(dt));            but when I try to replace with the string that I enter I am getting an error "Input string was not in a correct format".This is my code to replace : lformat = new stringbuilder(dt.lower()).Replace("dw",dayofweek.ToString()) . Any suggestions on this. Also is there a way to find the quarterly number of the year.

Comment: Yes thanks again. I am using  "string quarter = (((dt.Month - 1) / 3) + 1).ToString();" but yours seem simpler than mine.

Comment: I am looking for the string fomat for TimeStamp in C#. Is there anything other than "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:sss"?