# Get week number and year as YYYYWW from current date (SSIS script task) plus N weeks in the future

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, nodatime

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592650/week-number-for-a-year-in-dateformat-in-c-sharp) which explains how I might get the relevant week number.

Does anyone know how I could change the format to Year and Week like this `YYYYWW` i.e. `201317`.

Based on it being week 17, how could I get the correct Year and Week in N weeks time? i.e. 60 weeks from the current week including the current week? but as `YYYYWW` with the correct Year and Week number in that given year?

I am trying to do this in a script component of an SSIS package 2008 which supports up to .NET 3.5.

I have also tried referencing NodaTime in a Script Task inside the package and I can reference it fine and build the script, but when it comes to executing the task just on my machine, I get a `FileNotFound Exception` for NodaTime.dll.

Any help trying to achieve this just using .NET 3.5 and C# would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Here is an example of some of the week data I have recently been given. I didn't know my exact requirement and I still don't really know. This looks to me like the weeks start on a Sunday and that there is no leap week at the end of this year. I can only guess at whether this is the Gregorian calendar or a modification of it.

[image]

Comment: You need to work out *exactly* what week numbering scheme you're talking about. Please clarify.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have made an update to try and help clarify what I am after, thanks.

Comment: That doesn't actually give quite enough detail. As a good example, what would you expect the year and week for 2007-12-31 to be? Under ISO-8601, it would be week 53 of 2008. An actual specification would be helpful here. If you haven't got one, you need to ask for one.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I can't currently say, they only work with current and future years. They use them for a projection forecast for the next 3 years from the start of the current year but I don't think they have enough information to give me to work out what the actual requirements are :(

Comment: Who is "they"? *Someone* must know what rules you're meant to follow. If I were you, I would strongly push back - you could easily come up with something which works for all the examples you've given, but violates the unstated rules later on :(

Comment: @JonSkeet "They" being the client. Thanks for your reply, hopefully they will eventually give me some concrete rules to go on.

Comment: @Pricey One possible good measure *might* be looking back at data from the end of 2007, and beginning of 2008. Per [the article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx) John Skeet linked, `12/31/2007` (Monday) should return 53 for `GetWeekOfYear` and 1 for ISO 8601. Depending on what their data says, we know it may be one or the other (or neither0.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very simple method to calculate the current week using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`:

```
using System.Globalization;

CalendarWeekRule weekRule = CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek;
DayOfWeek firstWeekDay = DayOfWeek.Monday;
Calendar calendar = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

int currentWeek = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, weekRule, firstWeekDay)
```

The above method will almost (see Jon Skeet's [linked article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx)) return the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) [week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date); this is the standard used by many governments and industries (including import/export, and multi-national companies).

In order to get the desired format of `YYYYWW`, simply use:

```
String myYYYYWW = String.Format("{0:0000}{1:00}", DateTime.Now.Year, currentWeek);
```

To obtain `N` weeks in the future, you can let the `DateTime` class do the calculation for you...

```
DateTime myFutureWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(N * 7); // add N weeks

// ... steps outlined above ...

int futureWeek = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(myFutureWeek, weekRule, firstWeekDay)
```

---

If you'd like to *deviate* from the almost-ISO week number, simply change the `weekRule` and `firstWeekDay` variables. You may also want to play around with the `calendar` of specific cultures.

The Wikipedia article on ISO week date, contains a section for [other week numbering systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Other_week_numbering_systems), such as that used in the United States.

Comment: I just realized that you had linked to a question that provided most of this same information...

Comment: This doesn't *quite* correspond to ISO-8601. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx (Noda Time supports ISO-8601 behaviour here, but *only* that behaviour. So if the OP wants exact ISO behaviour, using Noda Time would be a good bet. Otherwise, the BCL should be fine.)

Comment: Thanks for the information on formatting and other week numbers along with your example. I don't think I can use ISO-8601 but this is still useful information.

Comment: @Pricey: It's not a matter of "what you can use" - it's a matter of "what your requirements are". You've given *examples*, but no rules. Where do your requirements come from, and how precise are they? EDIT: I've just reread the question where you say you basically don't *have* requirements, just examples. I strongly suggest you do no further work on it until you've managed to *get* the requirements.

Comment: @JonSkeet Great info! I had previously used the BCL's week calculation, and wasn't aware of it not being *exactly* ISO 8601. I would've given a Noda Time example, but I haven't had the need to use it yet. =\